# net::ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200

Tags: javascript, html, nginx, cdn

Access the index.html homepage and pull JS files to report an error，messages:net::ERR_QUIC_PROTOCOL_ERROR 200
The console reports an error, the far right prompts login: 37, click and locate such a piece of code：

```
const changeFavicon = link => {
        let $favicon = document.head.querySelector('link[rel="icon"]');
        if ($favicon !== null) {
          $favicon.href = link;
        } else {
          $favicon = document.createElement("link");
          $favicon.rel = "icon";
          $favicon.href = link;
          document.head.appendChild($favicon);
        }
      };
      let iconUrl = localStorage.getItem('company.icon') || '/favicon.ico';
      changeFavicon(iconUrl);
      window.document.title = localStorage.getItem('company.name') || 'test';
```

There is no idea, this is in the browser refresh button, right-click to clear cache hard loading will report this problem, how to troubleshoot this problem？